# How to iterate over an array to initialize a button?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, button, swiftui

This is my code and what I'm trying to do is to create buttons and set the text to their corresponding values in the array and then increase the value by 1 when they are tapped. I am currently getting the error "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'"

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var counterValues = [0, 0, 0];
    @State var i = 0;
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("Button Type")

            for i in counterValues.count {
                Button(action: {
                 self.counterValues[i] += 1;

                }) {
                    Text("\(counterValues[i])")
                     .font(.title)
                     .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

                }
                i += 1;
            }


        }


    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I also attempted to do a ForEach(0 ..< counterValues.count) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` or `ForEach` constructs need a `Range` - `count` is just an `Int`.  So, you could say `for i in 0..<counterValues.count`, but you can use `ForEach` with the array's `indices` property to get this range directly -

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    var counterValues = [0,0,0]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(counterValues.indices) { index in
                Button(action: {
                    self.counterValues[index] += 1
                }) {
                    Text("\(self.counterValues[index])")
                    .font(.title)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```